# Is there a general, exhaustive list of forms of integrand that can be tackled using integration by substitution?

Tags: calculus, integration

My textbook doesn't explain u-substitution in a very general way. Through looking at examples, I have tried to come up with a general set of conditions for using u-substitution as an integration technique.

The most basic form seems to be

$ \int {k \: h'(x)f'(h(x))} \: dx$

Additionally, this if there is another function of $h(x)$, then it can be integrated in terms of h(x) as well.

$ \int{k \: g(h(x))h'(x)f'(h(x))} \: dx$

I guess there could be any finite number of such functions of $h(x)$ as part of the term.

Out of these elements multiplying with $ {f'(h(x))}$, $h'(x)$ is the only necessary one.

Finally, if an expression can be transformed into ether of these forms without changing the actually value of the expression (e.g. through trig identities or multiplying the numerator and denominator of a ratio),  then it can also be integrated using u-substitution.

I believed that these cases were exhaustive. However, I then came across:

$\int{\frac{1+ \sin{x}}{\cos{x}}} dx $

This can be solved by multiplying by $\frac{1}{h'(x)}$:

$\frac{1+ \sin{x}}{\cos{x}} \times \frac{1}{\cos{x}} = \frac{1 + \sin{x}}{\cos^2{x}}$

Applying the the trig identity $ \sin^2{\theta} + \cos^2{\theta} \equiv 1 $ transforms it into $ g(h(x))f'(h(x)) $:

$\frac{1+ \sin{x}}{1 - \sin^2{x}} = \frac{1 + \sin{x}}{(1 + \sin{x})(1 - \sin{x})} = \frac{1}{1 - \sin{x}}          $

Therefore, if $u = h(x) = \sin{x}$ ,

$\int{\frac{1 + \sin{x}}{\cos{x}}} dx  =  \int{\frac{1}{1 - u}} du = ln| 1 - u| + c = ln|1 - sin x| + c  $

Thus, I have added a third category, one for expressions that can be transformed into an integrable function of $ u $ or $ h'(x)$ once the $ \times \frac{1}{h'(x)}$ transformation has been applied.

Is this an exhaustive, general list of cases where u-substitution can be applied as an integration technique? Are there are any resources (e.g. online textbooks, etc.) which might have such a list?

Comment: Since David K beat me to answering, I'll just add that what is going on with $\int \frac{1+\sin x}{\cos x}\,dx$ is rewriting the integrand using trigonometric properties:$$\frac{1+\sin x}{\cos x} = \frac{\cos x}{1 - \sin x}$$ and then noting that it is now in the form $f(u)u'$ where $f(u) = \frac 1{1-u}$ and $u = \sin x$.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Yes, this clears up that integrand to me. I can file it under 'manipulate into $ f(u) u' $ without changing the actual value of the integrand'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first form is already more "general" than it needs to be, in my opinion. I would simply write

$$\newcommand{d}{\mathrm d}  \int  f'(h(x))h'(x)\, \d x. \tag1 $$

Yes, you can put a factor of $k$ in the integrand, but since 
$\frac{\d}{\d u} kf(u) = k \frac{\d}{\d u} f(u),$
it doesn't buy you any new integrals that you can solve;
you could just have taken whatever you were going to use for $f$ and multiplied it by $k$ before giving it the name $f,$ and then you'd be able to write your integral in the form shown above. Alternatively, use the rule 
$\int k r(u)\, \d u = k \int r(u)\, \d u$ to deal with the factor of $k$ before you use substitution.

The thing that makes this a *substitution* is that when you replace $h(x)$ with a variable, for example by the substitution $u = h(x),$ you find that

$$ \int  f'(h(x))h'(x)\, \d x = \int f'(u) \,\d u. \tag2$$

By the way, this is why I prefer to write $f'(h(x))h'(x)$ instead of $h'(x)f'(h(x)).$
Writing $h'(x)$ directly adjacent to $\d x$ helps me remember that the $\d u$ on the right-hand side of $(2)$ replaces $h'(x)$ as well as $\d x$.

The right hand side now is solved just by applying one of the fundamental theorems of calculus:

$$ \int f'(u) \,\d u = f(u) + C. $$

But then we remember that we defined $u$ as a function of $x$:

$$ f(u) + C = f(h(x)) + C. $$

And that's why

$$ \int  f'(h(x))h'(x)\, \d x = f(h(x)) + C. $$

I don't even see the point of a rule with an extra factor of $g(h(x)).$
After all, how does this help us solve the integral?
The substitution $u = h(x)$ gives us

$$ \int g(h(x)) f'(h(x))h'(x)\, \d x = \int g(u) f'(u) \,\d u. \tag3$$

Solving this integral comes down to finding a function $r$ such that
$r'(u) = g(u) f'(u).$ So really the right-hand side of $(3)$ is just
$$ \int r'(u) \,\d u $$
or (after undoing the substitution $u = h(x)$)
$$ \int r'(h(x)) h'(x)\,\d x, $$
which is just $(1)$ with the trivial change of using a function named $r$ instead of a function named $f.$

---

Another way to look at it is that $f'$ in $(1)$ simply represents "some function I know how to integrate." The fact that it might be possible to write this function as the product of a second function times the derivative of a third function is just making a (relatively) simple rule needlessly complicated.

By the way, there will be times when the story is not quite so simple, because you cannot immediately solve the integral by substitution. The substitution might occur only within one of the steps of another method (such as integration by parts), or the substitution might leave you with an integral that requires you to apply another method to finally solve it.
I would not attempt to fold those possibilities into a "general" substitution rule, however; you'll come up with a "rule" that is far too complicated and it will still not cover all the possible applications, since you could have arbitrarily many applications of other rules in the solution of your integral.

---

Now about multiplying by $\frac{1}{h'(x)},$ if you consider the integrand to be a function of $x,$ and if we give that function the name $p,$ then the integral is

$$  \int p(x)\, \d x.$$

But we want to express this in the form of $(1)$,  which means we need to find functions $f$ and $h$ such that

$$ p(x) = f'(h(x)) h'(x). $$

And of course this means that

$$ f'(h(x)) = \frac{p(x)}{h'(x)} . $$

So there's your multiplication by  $\frac{1}{h'(x)}.$  It's not just a variation of the rule, it *is* the rule.

Comment: (+1) for (among other things) "it doesn't buy you any new integrals that you can solve; you could just have taken whatever you were going to use for $f$ and multiplied it by $k$ before giving it the name $f$" I was thinking of pretty much the same thing when I read the question and was trying to decide whether I should make a comment to this effect when I saw that you've already done it.

Comment: So, the most general form for substitution is $\int f'(h(x))h'(x) dx$, where $ f'$ is integrable. Ultimately, the integrand has to be in this form for substitution to work. However, I guess that leaves two possibilities for the *initial* form of the integrand: integrands already resemble $f'(h(x))h'(x)$ or which can be manipulated into that form. This is more what I was thinking about when I wrote

Comment: ... $g(x)f'(h(x))h'(x)$. E.g. $(\sin{x})(\sin{x}+1)^3(\cos{x})$ can be manipulated into $f'(h(x))h'(x)$, but $(\cot{x})(\sin{x}+1)^3(\cos{x})$ cannot be. So, on reflection, I guess my question was more about identifying *manipulability* into $f'(h(x))h'(x) $ even though this has definitely cleared a lot of things up

Comment: There are cases where the integrand is "already written" in the form $f'(h(x))h'(x),$ that is, you have an expression that is clearly the product of two smaller expressions, one of which just happens to work as $h'(x),$ and you see this right away. And then there are cases where you have to look harder for $h(x).$ You might find that you need to apply another substitution after the first one; your last integral would be an example of this (substituting for $1 - u$) except that you probably worked out a more general version of it earlier and it is now a known integral to you.